# How to set Alphabetical sections in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm stuck at this point, where I want to set alphabetical section with the right cells in them. So far I have been able to add section from "a" to "z", but all my cells get listed under all sections. I can't come up with a soution which sorted the cells under the right section. Hope you guys can help - thank you.

Here is my code so far:

```
var PersonName: [String?]? = []
var PersonNumber : [Array<String?>?]? = []
var Dic:[String:String?]? = [String:String?]?()

let sections:Array<String> = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return self.sections
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
        atIndex index: Int) -> Int{

            return index
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{

        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (PersonName?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = PersonName![indexPath.row]!
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = PersonNumber![indexPath.row]!.first!

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

            return self.sections[section]
    }
```

Comment: You need your data source to be an array of arrays where each subarray is just the data for the given letter.

Answer (score 0):

What you need Here is to Format your data like following

You need array contains dictionary with key as alphabets to show as section  and value as Array or Mutable Array to show as row

`( { a : ( {(apple), (air) , (ant) } ) }
 { b : ( {(ball), (bat) , (boost) } ) }
)`

Hope it  helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 'Array of Array' to achieve this. Check out the code 
  below to do so.

```
  var nameList = ["Abc","Bbc","Cbc",......]//whatever it is
  var arrNameList = [[nameList]]()
  var str = String()

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" //Sections to make

    for i : Int in 0 ..< (str.count) { //loop to get section
        var arr = [nameList]() //Create temp array
        for j : Int in 0 ..< nameList.count { //loop to get name
            let name = nameList[j]
            let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
            let char = str[index]
            if name.first == char { 
                arr.append(name)
            }
        }
        arrNameList.append(arr) 
     }
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arrNameList.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection 
  section: Int) -> String? {
    let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: section)
    let char = str[index]
    return char
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
  section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrNameList[section].count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection 
  section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
    for: indexPath) as! NameListTableViewCell

    let name = arrNameList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLbl.text = name

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Hope it helps..